# Use golangci-lint with lsp-mode

Tags: flycheck, lsp-mode, golang

How can I set up `golangci-lint` as the linter with my config? I've tried using `flycheck-golangci-lint` but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm testing my config by opening a .go file with an ineffectual assignment that trips `golangci-lint` when run from the CLI tool. My Go and LSP configs are:

```lisp
;; lsp-mode configs
(use-package lsp-mode
  :delight lsp-lens-mode ""
  :ensure t
  :init
  ;; set prefix for lsp-command-keymap (few alternatives - "C-l", "C-c l")
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :custom
  (lsp-auto-guess-root +1)
  :config
  (lsp-enable-imenu)
  (setq lsp-prefer-flymake nil)
  (setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable t)
  :hook (;; replace XXX-mode with concrete major-mode(e. g. python-mode)
         (python-mode . lsp-deferred)
     (scala-mode . lsp-deferred)
     (sh-mode . lsp-deferred)
         (go-mode . lsp-deferred)
         ;; if you want which-key integration
         (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
     (lsp-mode . lsp-lens-mode)
     (lsp-after-open . 'lsp-enable-imenu)
     )
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred))

;; go-mode
(use-package go-mode
  :delight ""
  :hook
  (before-save . lsp-format-buffer)
  (before-save . lsp-organize-imports)
  )

;; flycheck-golang-ci-lint
(use-package flycheck-golangci-lint
  :ensure t
  :hook
  (go-mode . flycheck-golangci-lint-setup)
  )
```

Apologies for the wall of code - I want to make sure I don't miss anything that might be causing `flycheck-golang-ci-lint` to fail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to chain `golangci-lint` after `lsp`, is it? The following snippet allows you to chain other linters after `lsp`. I have included the link where the original solution was posted for other linters. You can see that I use the snippet to chain linters for `Python` and `Shell`.

```
;; https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1762
(progn
  (with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
    (defvar-local flycheck-local-checkers nil)

    (defun flycheck-checker-get (fn checker property)
      (or (alist-get property (alist-get checker flycheck-local-checkers))
          (funcall fn checker property)))

    (advice-add 'flycheck-checker-get :around 'flycheck-checker-get)

    (add-hook 'lsp-managed-mode-hook
              (lambda ()
                (when (derived-mode-p 'python-mode)
                  (setq flycheck-local-checkers '((lsp . ((next-checkers . (python-pylint)))))))

                (when (derived-mode-p 'sh-mode)
                  (setq flycheck-local-checkers '((lsp . ((next-checkers . (sh-shellcheck)))))))
               
                (when (derived-mode-p 'go-mode)
                  (setq flycheck-local-checkers '((lsp . ((next-checkers . (golangci-lint)))))))
      ))
  ))
```

I do not use `go`, so unfortunately I cannot test the code.